# Angularjs-route href not evaluated

Tags: javascript, angularjs, href, ngroute

When I try to route from /players to /players/:playerId in my Angularjs-porject the URL updates to players#/players/4173 and not to the desired players/4173. This is the href:

```
<a href="#/players/4173">playerName</a>
```

and this is the route config:

```
when('/players/:playerId', {
      template: '<player-detail></player-detail>'
    })
```

I can manually type .../players/4173 and it works, but when clicking it does not work and I see the URL

```
.../players#%2Fplayers%2F4173
```

What's wrong?

**NOTE:**
The live code from Angularjs own tutorial has the same error in my browser:

http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-8/app/

**SOLVED:**

## /#!/players/playerId

They missed that (#!) in the early example code of the tutorial I followed.

Comment: <a href="#/players/4173">playerName</a> remove the players and check

Comment: Now I get players#%2F4173, not working

Comment: change your a tag <a href="/4173"> and try for checking purpose for URL

Comment: Error 404 - not exist:  http://localhost:8080/4173

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you now navigate to `/index.html`, you are redirected to `/index.html#!/players` than your links should look like this:

```
<a href="#!/players/4173">playerName</a>
```

Comment: No, same problem. I followed angularjs own totural: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_08 and now I noticed that their live code has the same problem, check it: http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-8/app/

Comment: If you check correctly you send me the link to "8 - Templating Links & Images" and the part  for routing and multiples views is on: "9 - Routing & Multiple Views". Here i send you the link https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09 and also you should check the "Code diff" from step 8 to step 9 at: https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat/compare/step-8...step-9

Comment: Here is the link to the demo at Step 10: http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-10/app/#!/phones that's what you want to achieve

Comment: Thank's they must have missed to include #! in the previous example. #!/players/playerId is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove "players/" part in your URL and see if it works. Currently it is duplicated.

Comment: I did that see above comments

Answer (score 0):

Hi change your a tag like this

```
  <a class="pointer" ng-click="players(4173)" >
```

**JS**

```
$scope.players = function(_data){
        $state.go('players',{'playersid':_data});
    }
```

**config.js**

```
.state('players', {
            url: '/players?playersid',
            templateUrl: 'views/xxgg/timeline.html',
            controller: 'campaignTimeline',
            params: {
                 'playersid': null
             }

        })
```

Comment: I tried but $stateprovider is apperently to old or something for this project. Can't add angular-ui-router.js. But thanks!